# Only generate string with a Max of X length and Min of X

Tags: php, memory, max, permutation

I have a script which generates all possible permutations of something. Thing is, I don't know how to make it only list a max of, lets say, 10 characters and minimum of 3 characters.

```
<?php 
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');

$possible = "abcdefghi";

$input = "$possible";

function string_getpermutations($prefix, $characters, &$permutations)
{
    if (count($characters) == 1)
        $permutations[] = $prefix . array_pop($characters);
    else
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($characters); $i++)
        {
            $tmp = $characters;
            unset($tmp[$i]);

            string_getpermutations($prefix . $characters[$i], array_values($tmp), $permutations);
        }
    }
}
$characters = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++)
    $characters[] = $input[$i];
$permutations = array();

print_r($characters);
string_getpermutations("", $characters, $permutations);

print_r($permutations);

?>
```

Currently outputs about 400,000 possibilities and that's a tiny fraction of what I want.
(I literally want it to do ALL possibilities, which will be a huge problem with memory usage, but that's another problem.)

Does somebody know how to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to create? Something to check every possible password?

Comment: Yeah putvande, not sure if it's a great idea but that's what I'm going with.